# I.m Getting "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null" when uploading image with axios in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, axios

Why I'm getting

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

when uploading an image as below.
Request payload is looks like

------WebKitFormBoundaryU2XJIVhmCHdi06EH

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="download (3).jfif"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryU2XJIVhmCHdi06EH--

in my blade file

```
 <form action="" id="img_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onchange="uploadImage()">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onchange="uploadImage()">

 </form>
```

Js Code

```
function uploadImage(event) {
        console.log('image');
        const formData = new FormData();
        const imagefile = document.querySelector('#image');
        formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0])
        // formData.append("image_2", imagefile.files[0]);
        console.log('formdata' +formData);
        axios.post('upload/image', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': imagefile.type
                // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2)
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('response' + response.data);

        });
    }
```

In My laravel Controller

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){

    
    $file = $request->file('image');

    $name =  $file->getClientOriginalName().'-'.time() ;
    $filePath = 'images/' .  $name;
    Storage::disk('public')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));

    $get_url = Storage::disk('public')->url($filePath);

    return response()->json([
        'name' => $name,
        'url' => $get_url
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your request dosent have file as 'image_ad' , so use it:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
```

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @IndunilLakshitha at first line write dd($request->all()) and see what you sent